# One-dimensional data in spatstat

Tags: r, statistics, spatstat

I have data of one-dimensional points (locations in a straight line). I want to check if the cluster poisson process models or Cox models are a good fit for the data.

Since my data only has x-coordinate, I tried the linear network poisson process model. However, `lppm` supports only Poisson models.

The `kppm` methods, which have the cluster models, require two-dimensional data. So, I added a dummy y-column with `zero` values and range of `(ymin=0,ymax=0.001)`. `ymax=0` returns errors during computation. Now, I am able to fit Matern cluster, etc.

My question is what would be the best way to handle one-dimensional data?

Is adding a dummy column with a non-zero range the only solution? Or is there some detail about point patterns or process models that I have missed? Suggestions for alternatives are also welcome.

Comment: I am not sure why you would want to use Cox Modeling here as it is a proportional survival (or hazard model) and poisson processing is a clustering model...which with a straight line becomes a bit obscure. Whether or not a model is appropriate has a lot to do with what you intend to ask of your data...what is your question? Be very clear about what you need to do with the data and why, that will get you farther in the right direction.

Comment: The points in our data tend to occur in clusters. It also satisfies some conditions of a Poisson point process like independence of disjoint partitions, etc. So we are thinking of modeling the data using clustered Poisson process where the cluster centres have a Poisson distribution and each cluster has a finite number of points. I think that Cox processes are much more general and include the cluster processes.

If we are able to find a model which is a **good fit** for our data then we plan to use it in further calculations of higher level structures built using those points.

Comment: I think this post on stats.stack gets at what you need. With linear data points it is more about estimated the punctuated distances between intervals of data. See if this gets you headed in the right direction: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40454/determine-different-clusters-of-1d-data-from-database

Comment: To give some more idea about one of our datasets - it has around 100K points in the observation window of length 50M.

Comment: it all comes down to the resolution of your data, how precise and accurate are the measurements. The analysis is blind to scale, so you could change the magnitude to bigger integers to cluster and then scale it back down after if you need to...but I do think that some sort of interval measurement or kernel density estimation would be more defensible. The simplest path to your desired outcome....

Answer (score 2):

First can I point out that other commentators have confused the *Cox Point Process* with the *Cox proportional hazards model* -- two completely different things, invented by the same person.

A Cox point process is a perfectly valid model for the data in this context.

Cox point process models for data on a linear network (like a street network) are not yet supported in the `spatstat` package. However you can fit such models using the minimum contrast fitting procedure. First compute the estimated 1-D pair correlation function or K-function from your data (using `linearK` or `linearpcf`). Then use `mincontrast` to fit the desired model. You will have to write a small piece of code to compute the theoretical value of the K function or pcf for the desired model. See `help(mincontrast)`.

Comment: Thanks, will look at the functions you mentioned and update with the results.